# How to create a new linked list by reading from a text file

Tags: c++

Hi Guys I am working on an assignment of data structures which says:

Consider a library database comprising of students records with the following
attributes:

• Book ID (auto generated ID, e.g. 1240)

• Book Title (maximum of 30 characters)

• Author Name (maximum of 30 characters; consider single/first author only)

• Publisher Name (maximum of 30 characters, e.g. Pearson)

• Year of Edition (e.g., 2000)

• Status (issued/not issued. Hint: you can use a flag variable for this)

• Date of Issue/Returned (if issued, shows that date of issue; otherwise shows

the date of last returned. Format: ddmmyyyy.)

Your job is to write a C/C++ code to be able to perform the following operations on the library database. You are required to use a single-linked list for this program.
**1. Assign dynamic memory for an initial list of five books. Initially store data for five books, using assignment statements.**

**2. Next, open a text file List1.txt using file streams in C/C++ and write this data from memory into a permanent storage device .**

**1. Now, given the data is permanently stored into a file, implement C/C++ routines which should be able to perform the following functions:

**a. Read the text file List1.txt using C/C++ file streams, and temporarily load
this data into a linked-list L1 with the header named as ListHead1**

What i have done so far 
created a linked list and stored it into a file but i am having trouble to reload data from file and store it into a new linked list What i have tried so far for:

Librecord* read_from_List1(Librecord *head){

```
Librecord *newbook , *end;
ifstream infile("List1.txt");

if(infile.is_open()) {
    while(infile.good()){ 
        newbook = new Librecord;
        infile >> newbook -> bookID;
        getline(infile >> newbook -> title , '\n');
        getline(infile >> newbook -> author_name, '\n');
        getline(infile >> newbook -> publisher_name , '\n');
        infile >> newbook -> year_of_edition;
        infile >> newbook -> status;
        getline(infile , newbook -> issue_or_return_date,'\n');

        newbook -> next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL){
            head = newbook;
            end = newbook;
        }   
        else
            end -> next = newbook;
            end = newbook;
    }
    infile.close();
}
else
    cout << "Error openning file" << endl;
return head;
```

}

**On compiling this i get an error message about compatibility of getline function**

**[Error] no matching function for call to 'getline(std::basic_istream&, char)'**

**I just switched from java to c++ and tried a lot but couldn't find a way any help will be much appreciated**

**MY text file have data:**

1

Intro to java programming

Y daniel Liang

Pearson

2009

0

13-11-2015

2

Intro to java programming

Y daniel Liang

Pearson

2009

1

13-11-2015

3

Thinking in java

G Reynolds

McGraw Hill

2011

0

2-1-2017

4

Ethics in IT

J M Kizza

Pearson

2006

1

13-3-2017

5

C++ How to program

Dietel & Dietel

Dietel Inc

2012

0

23-10-2014

**and structure looks like this**

```
int autoBookID = 0;
    struct Librecord{
        int bookID = ++autoBookID; 
        char title[30];
        char author_name[30];
        char publisher_name[30];
        int year_of_edition;
        bool status;
        char issue_or_return_date[11];
        Librecord *next;
    };
```

Comment: did you already try to read some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)? There is no `getline(std::basic_istream&,char)` and thats what the error is trying to tell you

Comment: I tried a lot but can't find an alternative as if i do this infile >> ttitle; infile >> author_name it reads only upto white space but i want to read whole line tobi303

Comment: change all your `char[]` in `Librecord` to `std::string`

Comment: Recommend you write x->y instead of x -> y.

Comment: But it is pre condition for structure to use character arrays not string

Comment: I can't find any difference in writing x->y and x -> y

Comment: one important difference is that you wont find `x -> y` when you search for `x->y` unless you use regular expressions which is kind of overkill for such a common search

Comment: "But it is pre condition for structure to use character arrays not string" `std::string` is basically a character array in disguise hiding all the ugly stuff while keeping all you need

Answer (score 0):

```
newbook = new Librecord;
infile >> newbook -> bookID;
getline(infile >> newbook -> title , '\n');  <---
getline(infile >> newbook -> author_name, '\n'); <---
getline(infile >> newbook -> publisher_name , '\n'); <---
infile >> newbook -> year_of_edition;
infile >> newbook -> status;
getline(infile , newbook -> issue_or_return_date,'\n');
```

Inside of marked `getline()` calls you are calling `infile>>newbook->...`, this gets resolved and returns reference to `istream`, after that your `getline()` tries to resolve for 2 arguments, `istream` and `char`, but it doesn't exist.

In your last `getline()` you are actually calling this properly, by passing `istream` reference, then pointer to `char` array and then `char` delimiter.

To solve your error you should change earlier `getline()` calls. Or in simpler words: fixy a typo.